# Using sed, add line X lines above match

Tags: text-processing, sed

I know that to prepend/append something, I just have to do:

```
sed -i '/pattern/a new thing!'
```

However, I'd like to match a line, and prepend something two lines higher.

I'd like to limit tools only to those which come out of the box with ubuntu 12.04, I don't know if `awk` fits the bill.

Just in case I'm pursuing solution to problem B while I need solution to A:
Excerpt of .m3u8 file looks like this:

```
#EXTINF:4.304300,
output-000.ts
#EXTINF:5.705700,
output-001.ts
#EXTINF:4.304300,
output-002.ts
#EXTINF:5.705700,
output-003.ts
```

Now, my goal is to insert a line 2 lines before every X'th `output-XXX.ts`. For example I want to achieve this:

```
#Inserted line 0
#EXTINF:4.304300,
output-000.ts
#EXTINF:5.705700,
output-001.ts
#Inserted line 1
#EXTINF:4.304300,
output-002.ts
#EXTINF:5.705700,
output-003.ts
```

Comment: As I stated, it has to go every Xth occurance of targeted pattern, in this example every second time. My script allows to modify that number, but I kind of assumed that utility tools don't know math to do stuff like that.

Comment: Oh, also the content is ascending integer sequence starting from 0, mirroring which match is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` (installed by default on POSIX systems including ubuntu):

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk -v X=2 '
  NR >= 2 && /^output-[0-9]{3}\.ts$/ && ++n % X == 1 {
    print "#Inserted line", i++
  }
  NR>1 {print last}
  {last = $0}
  END{if (NR) print last}' < file.in > file.out
```

That's for 2 lines above. To generalise to N lines above:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk -v N=2 -v X=2 '
  BEGIN{N--}
  NR > N {
    if (/^output-[0-9]{3}\.ts$/ && ++n % X == 1)
      print "#Inserted line", i++
    print l[NR % N]
  }
  {l[NR % N] = $0}
  END{
    for (i = NR > N ? NR - N + 1 : 1; i <= NR; i++) print l[i % N]
  }'
```

Comment: I think I'll go with your solution. But stupid question, shall I use `awk... < myfile...`, `cat myfile | awk...`, or...? I can't seem to get desired output using those. (and `awk ... myfile` doesn't insert lines as well)

Comment: It seems that `n` (not `N`) is empty when I test it using else and printing it. I don't know much about awk, should variable be initialized beforehand?

Comment: Ok, that should be enough spam for today: It seems my awk doesn't support curly braces in regex. I'll google some more. Thank you!

Comment: @Misiur, that'll be an old version of gawk where {} were not enabled unless in POSIX compatibility mode. Best is to use the POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 like in my update to make it work without affecting compatibility with other awk implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
< .m3u8  perl -ne 'push @w, $_;
                   unshift @w, "#Inserted line " . (0 + $c++) . "\n"
                       if /^output-[0-9]+\.ts/ && 0 == $m++ % 2;
                   print shift @w while @w > 1;
                   }{ print @w;'
```

`@w` is the "sliding window" array that keeps the last 2 lines. `$m` contains the number of matches, i.e. the number of "output-XXXX" lines encountered so far, so if modulo 2 it gives 0, you pick up every 2nd match. `unshift` inserts a line to the window array at the beginning, `shift` retrieves it. At the end, you have to output the remaining lines.